# Can a smoke alarm with cut wires cause a fire?

Tags: fire-hazard, smoke-detectors

Can a smoke alarm with cut wires cause a fire? Not, that it might not detect a fire (I don't expect it to any more), but that the smoke detector itself may cause a fire.

For my specific case, I cut the red and black wires shown (pretty much all of them), and one of the ribbons running to the large silver capacitor/battery capped in yellow. See below for explanation as to why I did this. It is a smoke detector with direct electrical power through the building, and battery backup. Is it possible this could cause a fire?
[image]

As for why I did this, there is a reason, though not a good one. I came back from a bunch of long flights to my tiny apartment, I haven't been able to sleep for a long time and I'm feeling sick. In this stupor, doing anything to stop the low battery alarm so I could sleep was all I could think to do. Try as I might, I couldn't get the alarm off the ceiling, but the cover plate came off. So I cut the wires. Since it kept beeping, I cut the metal ribbon to the large capacitor/battery shown with one end capped in yellow. It kept beeping, so I went to nearby hotel so I can sleep. Now that I'm there, rested slightly, and can actually think, I'm worried I might have setup a fire hazard (not the obvious hazard that the alarm probably no longer works, but that it might actually cause a fire). Someone will be there tomorrow to fix things, but I'm worried about the possibility of actually having caused a fire through what I did. Is this even possible? Or will things be ok until tomorrow?

Comment: It won't cause a fire, but why didn't you simply *change the battery*!? Now you'll be on the hook for replacing the entire detector :/

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, That was the original plan, but for one reason or another, I couldn't get it to detach from the ceiling. I struggled with trying to pull it off for 15 minutes or so before I resorted to the clipping the wires. It doesn't help that I didn't have a step ladder on hand (I will remedy that soon), and was balancing on a stack of books on top of a chair while feeling very lightheaded. In hindsight, there's a lot of different options I would have chosen before clipping the wires, but I was pretty out of it at the time. Thanks for the reassurance about the fire possibility.

Comment: you could have just cut the wire to the speaker, which would be safe and easy to fix later.

Comment: Depending where you are, you may have broken the law by tampering with fire detection device, e.g. https://www.revisor.mn.gov/statutes/cite/609.686 . Notify your landlord or building superintendent that this needs to be fixed.